# jquery equivalent to zippy in closure

Tags: jquery, widget, accordion, google-closure

I love this widget in google closure,
[Zippy](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/zippy.html)
and I need an equevalent in jquery. I'm pretty sure there is one. 
I found Accordion in jquery UI, but it is not the same behaviour. 
Unlike Accordion, which organizes a set of chunks and shows only one at a time, Zippy targets one chunk and toggles its visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily make your own plugin for such a simple task :

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.zippy = function(options) {
        var o = $.extend({}, options, $.fn.zippy.defaults);
        return this.each(function(i,el) {
            var $el = $(el),
                content = $el.find('p'),
                title = $el.find('h2');

            title.toggle(function() {
                content.slideToggle(o.duration, o.easing, o.callback);
            });
        });
    };
    $.fn.zippy.defaults = {
        easing : 'swing',
        duration : 500,
        callback : function(){}
    };
})(jQuery)
```

### Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7BLCY/1/).

Comment: great work, but Its behaviour is not the same with zippy though. It's animation is just open and close. The content doest not slide with it.